Unable to show clipboard menu such as copy or paste for image in webview Flutter (Android )
While long press on iOS the clipboard menu shows, but not working on android
Plugin: flutter_webview_plugin 0.4.0
class PaymentScreenBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaymentScreenBody({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PaymentSubscribeViewModel viewModel =
        ViewModel.watch<PaymentSubscribeViewModel>(context);
    return WebViewWidget(
        controller: viewModel.webController
          ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
          ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
          ..setNavigationDelegate(
            NavigationDelegate(
              onPageStarted: (String url) {},
              onPageFinished: (String url) {
                viewModel.paymentRedirection(url);
              },
              onHttpError: (HttpResponseError error) {},
              onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
              onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
                return NavigationDecision.navigate;
              },
            ),
          )
          ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(viewModel.paymentUrl.toString())));
  }
}

Flutter 3.24.0
Dart 3.5.0
Here is the output needed Click here
Here is the screenshot click here
